# How to use ternary operator with .foregroundStyle(primary: ShapeStyle, secondary: ShapeStyle)?

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, conditional-operator

I am trying to pass two arguments to this modifier

```
.foregroundStyle(primary: ShapeStyle, secondary: ShapeStyle)
```

I want the primary argument be based on isTrue Bool value using ternary operator, but I get errors.

It **works** with one argument version of this modifier:

```
.foregroundStyle(style: ShapeStyle)
.foregroundStyle((isTrue) ? Color.green : Color.secondary) // no error, works
```

But **does not work** with two arguments version of this modifier:

```
.foregroundStyle(primary: ShapeStyle, secondary: ShapeStyle)
.foregroundStyle((isTrue) ? Color.green, Color.blue : Color.secondary, Color.green) // Error: Expected ':' after '? ...' in ternary expression
```

Why it is not working? How to get rid of errors?

Full code:

```
 Image(systemName: isTrue ? "clock.badge.checkmark.fill" : "clock.fill")
         .symbolRenderingMode(.palette)
         .foregroundStyle(Color.blue, Color.red) // no error, works
         .foregroundStyle((isTrue) ? Color.green, Color.blue : Color.secondary, Color.green) // Error: Expected ':' after '? ...' in ternary expression
         .foregroundStyle((isTrue) ? (Color.green, Color.red) : (Color.secondary, Color.white)) // Error: Expected ':' after '? ...' in ternary expression
```

Answer (score 1):

Two arguments separated by comma:

```
 Image(systemName: isTrue ? "clock.badge.checkmark.fill" : "clock.fill")
         .symbolRenderingMode(.palette)
         .foregroundStyle((isTrue ? Color.green : Color.secondary), (isTrue ? Color.red : Color.white))
```

Comment: Thank you. But while this code gives me no errors, it seems to ignore the second argument :(

Comment: I mean it does not use either Color.red nor Color.white. Like never, whatever isTrue value is.

Comment: @user14119170 It works for me. When isTrue is true, the icon has red clock and green checkmark. When isTrue is false, checkmark is secondary color only as the icon "clock.fill" has only 1 color in palette rendering mode.

Comment: This works for me. Thank you.